# How to get access to Calendar events for a macOS command line tool in Swift 5 / Xcode 11

Tags: command-line-interface, swift5, eventkit

I want to write a *command line tool* in Swift 5 for macOS that adds events to the calendar. How do I give the app permission to access the calendar(s)?  All the docs I've found are for GUI apps with access to an info.plist and a string to display to the user.  Command line apps don't show an info.plist in Xcode. (How would the app display that alert anyway?)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No.  Never got an answer.